# Split first column into two and preserve rest in unix

Tags: unix

I need to split first column delimited by '#' into two columns. My data is in following format.

```
1#b,a
2#b,a
5#c,d
```

Required Output:

```
1,b,a
2,b,a
5,c,d
```

Other columns can have # in their values so I want to apply regex only on first column.

Thanks
Jitendra

Comment: I want to apply regex only on first column since other columns can also have #.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A file (file.orig) contains this:

```
1#b,a #
2#b,a #
5#c,d #
```

Use sed:

```
sed 's/#/,/1' file.orig > file.new
```

Output (`cat file.new`):

```
1,b,a #
2,b,a #
5,c,d #
```

Comment: Why did you edit that? I tested your sed command locally and I’m seeing the output of the previous version, which is also presuambly the correct answer for the question.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say where the data is.  I'll assume it's in a file.

```
tr '#' ',' < some_file.txt
```

Comment: The question has been edited since you answered to note that `#` can appear in other columns, so this is no longer a valid solution (`tr` changes any `#` anywhere).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yeah - I was doing something else for a couple of hours and when I came back, I noticed that the question had been modified, but it looked like cxc already addressed the change, so I didn't bother.

Comment: That's the way it goes.  I put the comment in so that people would not (I hope) downvote your originally valid but now invalid answer.  But downvoting is a risk you run leaving your answer unmodified and undeleted.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F, '{OFS=","}{gsub(/#/,",",$1);}1' your_file
```